# Can someone explain this error?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I'm new to Haskell and struggling with some subtleties of syntax. Why is this fine:

```
reduceBy a f n
    | n < 2 = (a,f)
    | (a `mod` n) == 0 = 
        reduceBy( floor $ fromIntegral a / fromIntegral n) (f++[n]) n
    | otherwise = (a, f)
```

While this has errors: (Couldn't match expected type `(a, [a])' against inferred type `[a] -> a -> (a, [a])' )

```
reduceBy a f n
    | n < 2 = (a,f)    
    | (a `mod` n) == 0 = 
        reduceBy( floor(fromIntegral a / fromIntegral n) (f++[n]) n )    
    | otherwise = (a, f)
```

?

Comment: `reduceBy (floor $ fromIntegral a / fromIntegral n) (f++[n]) n` is equivalent to `reduceBy (floor (fromIntegral a / fromIntegral n)) (f++[n]) n`.

Comment: As the first comment also shows, as a matter of style, whenever you need to parenthesize your arguments open parentheses are normally not placed right after the function, but at the start of the argument, e.g. `reduceBy (floor (...` instead of `reduceBy( floor( ...`.

Comment: p.s. `( floor $ fromIntegral a / fromIntegral n)` can be written as ``(a `div` n)``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your new closing parenthesis comes too late. It should be

```
... reduceBy (floor(fromIntegral a / fromIntegral n)) ...
```

The `$` binds fairly weakly, but parentheses trump everything.